# How to check if the drone is armed or not using MAVLink/MAVProxy?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mavlink

I want to run a python script when the drone is armed and stop running that python script when the drone is disarmed using MAVProxy. To check that I want to first check if the drone is armed or not. I tried 2 types of code but both of them are giving inconsistent results. It is showing armed but after some time it shows disarmed even though its armed.

I tried 2 types of code but both of them are giving inconsistent results. It is showing armed but after some time it shows disarmed even though its armed.

CODE 1:

```
from pymavlink import mavutil
#import sensor # logging file
import time
import sys

# Start a connection listening on a UDP port
# Once connected, use 'the_connection' to get and send messages


master = mavutil.mavlink_connection('/dev/ttyACM0')


while True:
       


# Wait for the connection to establish
 master.wait_heartbeat()


#Check if the drone is armed

 if master.motors_armed():
    print("The drone is armed.")
    #sensor.s_info('on')
    

 else:
    print("The drone is disarmed.")
    #sensor.s_info('off')

 time.sleep(2)
```

code 2:

```
 import time
 from pymavlink import mavutil
 import sensor # logging file

 # create a MAVLink connection
 master = mavutil.mavlink_connection('/dev/ttyACM0')

 while True:

 # check if the drone is armed
  armed = False



     # get the current system status
  msg = master.recv_match(type='HEARTBEAT', blocking=True)

     # check if the drone is armed

  armed = (msg.base_mode & mavutil.mavlink.MAV_MODE_FLAG_SAFETY_ARMED)
  if armed:
     print('Drone is armed')
     sensor.s_info('on')
 
  else:
     print('Drone is disarmed')
     sensor.s_info('off')
```

Answer (score 4):

I think it makes more sense to have the `while` `loop` depend on whether the drone is `armed` (`else` do some other thing):

```
...
while master.motors_armed():
    print('The drone is armed.')
    ...
else:
    print('The drone is disarmed.')
    ...
```

or

```
...
while mavutil.mavlink.MAV_MODE_FLAG_SAFETY_ARMED:
    print('The drone is armed.')
    ...
else:
    print('The drone is disarmed.')
    ...
```

or even

```
...
while (msg.base_mode & mavutil.mavlink.MAV_MODE_FLAG_SAFETY_ARMED):
    print('The drone is armed.')
    ...
else:
    print('The drone is disarmed.')
    ...
```

If you're using `DroneKit-SITL`:

```
...
while master.is_armable:
    print('The drone is armed.')
    ...
else:
    print('The drone is disarmed.')
    ...
```